# Return True/False for a matched or an unmatched floating point number using Regex in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, floating-point, boolean, pattern-matching

I need to print (True) for all the matched floating-point numbers in the user-defined input and (False) if the input is not a Floating point number.

I have so far come up with this:

```
import re

user_input = input() # the input will be (+4.9, 4.0, 2.89, 4, somerandomstuff)

pattern = re.compile(r'[+-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+') #pattern to match floating point numbers

matches = pattern.finditer(user_input)

for match in matches:
    print(bool(match))
```

**Expected Results:**

input = (+4.9, 4.0, 2.89, 4, somerandomstuff, stackoverflow)

True
True
True
False
False
False

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If user_input is a string with all the values, the pattern will only find the matched results. I think if you want to print False, you have to try to match each value individually.

Comment: Are you trying to match numerals that contain a decimal point? Can they contain an exponent, like `4.9e3`? A typical pattern for this is that the string either (a) has an optional sign (“+” or “-”), has a period with digits before it, digits after it, or both (but not neither), and optionally ends with an “e” or “E” followed by an optional sign followed by digits or (b) has an optional sign, digits, and that exponent part. I.e., the string contains a decimal point or an exponent or both. Given that, do you know how to write regular expressions for that? For parts of it?

Comment: @EricPostpischil no I am not trying to match exponents. Btw thanks.

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes I tried individual matching but I failed.

Comment: @Sheeban Something like https://ideone.com/6nqc9r

Comment: Then the pattern you want is likely: as an optional sign (“+” or “-”), has a period with digits before it, digits after it, or both (but not neither). The “hard part” is specifying digits before or after or both but not neither. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Strings with digits on only one side of the decimal point, such as “4.” or “.89”, are usually treated as floating-point literals, but that pattern rejects them.

Comment: The pattern rejects them because the regex I wrote doesn't want this to be considered as afloat. @Thefourthbird exactly what I needed thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user input will always have the format you provided you can use `float` and try to convert each value to float number. Also to filter out integers you can check for presence of `.` in each string.

```py
import re

user_input = input()

for match in user_input.strip("()").split(","):
    try:
        num = float(match)
        print("." in match)
    except ValueError:
        print(False)
```

Prints:

```
True
True
True
False
False
False
```

Comment: Yeah got your point but my main motive is to solve the problem using regex.